# How can I stop npm from modifying package-lock.json on production server

Tags: node.js, npm

I've narrowed down the issue to the OS npm is run on. I'm currently on OSx. When I run `npm install` on my local machine, it creates a new lockfile. When I push that lockfile to production and run `npm install` in production, it modifies the `package-lock.json` file.

However, if I install it on my Vagrant Ubuntu machine and push it to the production server (Ubuntu), the `package-lock.json` remains unmodified. How can I make it so that it stays consistent across operating systems?

Edit: npm version is 5.3.0 on host machine, virtual machine, and production server.

Diff of `package-lock.json` when originally run on Mac OSx, then `npm install` on an Ubuntu machine: https://paste.laravel.io/0MGNa

Comment: Can you show us the package.json and the relevant diffs in your lock file?

Comment: @E_net4 https://paste.laravel.io/0MGNa

Comment: `fsevents` is a macOS-only module, so it makes sense it gets removed on Ubuntu. I assume it's used by a dev dependency (`npm ls fsevents` should show what it's used by), so try `npm install --production`.

Comment: I need the dev dependencies to run tasks on the server though. Should I just gitignore the file?

Comment: Why do you want to prevent the prod lockfile from being changed?  Is there ever going to be an instance where what is deployed in prod will be commited back to the repo?

Comment: It causes git to be unable to pull changes due to conflicts.

Comment: I'm not sure of a cleaner way to accomplish this.  Maybe do a `git reset --hard` and then pull if you are able to modify your deployment scripts since you know that prod-side changes don't matter.  That should avoid the conflicts.

Comment: That's also a possibility, however I've decided to just ignore the file. Since it's possible the lock file can cause other people on different OS's to have problems.

Comment: Ignoring the lock file is not a good practice IMO, because you will end up with potential bugs caused by interactions between differing versions of installed packages that will only happen on specific machines and be extremely difficult to hunt down. The only solution I know of for this problem is to use Yarn and it's part of why FB created Yarn.

Answer (score 8):

For now, in 2018, the --no-save option will avoid modifications to the lockfile:

```
npm install --no-save
```

Starting with version v5.7.1 of npm:

```
npm ci
```

Answer (score 3):

Use [Yarn](https://github.com/yarnpkg/yarn) instead.

This is a common paint point with npm and there is no current solution other than to not use npm. Yarn does not have this problem. See https://github.com/npm/npm/issues/17722